# How do I return false for click handler for this button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a button that should open up a popup for a Facebook invite window but the button reloads the page. How to I handle this click so that it returns false? I.e. What is the syntactically correct way of doing this?

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
     $("a#invite_fb_friends").click(function() {
         FB.init({
             appId:'257395654482349',
             cookie:false,
             status:true
         });
         FB.ui({
             method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Test message. '
        });
      });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the problem? I mean...you can just add 'return false;' in your click method don't you?

Comment: It's a syntactical question. Do I add the return false and the semi-colon in the parenthesis?

Comment: Also have a look at [JavaScript: event.preventDefault() vs return false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: ummm... yes? I mean, just append it to the end of the method... see the answers.

Comment: Maybe this helps too: [MDN JavaScript Guide: Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function(){
       $("a#invite_fb_friends").click(function() {
         FB.init({
             appId:'257395654482349',
             cookie:false,
             status:true
         });
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Test message. '});

        return false;
        });
   });
</script>
```

is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `return false;` to the end of the function?

```
   $(function(){
       $("a#invite_fb_friends").click(function() {
           FB.init({
               appId:'257395654482349',
               cookie:false,
               status:true
           });
          FB.ui({
              method: 'apprequests',
              message: 'Test message. '
          });
          return false; //Disable default behavior.
        });
    });
```